# Node.js Cookie is not transmitted

Tags: node.js, cookies, express, socket.io

I'm use node.js + express + socket.io. 
But when I'm tring to use cookies - I'm getting an error

> no cookie transmitted

I have view all answers on this site. But don't find  solution.
Here is my code of server:

```
// Require server config
var server_config = require('./config.json');

// Require express
var express = require("express");
var MemoryStore = express.session.MemoryStore;
var app = express();
var sessionStore = new MemoryStore();

// Configure app
app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.session({secret: 'secret', key: 'express.sid'}));

    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(__dirname));
});

// Require socket IO and create server
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(server_config.port));

var history = {};
history.rooms = [];

var parseCookie = require('express/node_modules/cookie').parse;
io.set('authorization', function (data, accept) {
    // check if there's a cookie header
    if (data.headers.cookie) {
        // if there is, parse the cookie
        data.cookie = parseCookie(data.headers.cookie);
        // note that you will need to use the same key to grad the
        // session id, as you specified in the Express setup.
        data.sessionID = data.cookie['express.sid'];

        data.getSession = function (cb) {
            sessionStore.get(data.sessionID, function (err, session) {
                if (!err && !session) err = 'No session';
                data.session = session;
                cb(err, session);
            });
        }


    } else {
        // if there isn't, turn down the connection with a message
        // and leave the function.
        return accept('No cookie transmitted.', false);
    }
    // accept the incoming connection
    accept(null, true);
});

// On connection actions
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.handshake.getSession(function (error, session) {
        console.log(error);
    });

    // Draw action
    socket.on('drawClick', function (data) {
        // Push element to the history

        /*if (history.rooms[socket.room])
         history.rooms[socket.room].push(data);*/

        socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('draw', {socket_id: socket.id, shape: data.shape, canvas_id: data.canvas_id, history: data.history});
    });

    // Subscribe to a room
    socket.on('subscribe', function (data) {

        socket.room = data.room;
        socket.join(socket.room);

        // If room history does not exists - create it

        /*if (!history.rooms[socket.room])
         history.rooms[socket.room] = [];
         // If history exists - draw it
         else
         io.sockets.socket(socket.id).emit('history', {history: history.rooms[socket.room]});*/


    });

    // Note that it is not necessary to call socket.leave() during the disconnect event.
    // This will happen automatically. Empty rooms will be automatically pruned so there is no need to manually remove them.
    socket.on('unsubscribe', function (data) {
        socket.leave(socket.room);
    });

});
```

Here how I init on client:

```
io.connect(myprepa.config.site_url + ":" + myprepa.config.port);
```

Please help.

Comment: Works fine for me. I'm assuming that you're serving the client-side code through the same server?

Comment: Yes. Same server. http://myprepa.local on port 8888.

Comment: Here is my headers http://prntscr.com/2229mo

Comment: It looks like your HTML is being served from another port, though (no mention of port 8888 in the referer). Although that shouldn't matter, since cookies received for one port on host X should also be sent with requests to another port on the same host X.

Comment: Thank you, i will try ti fix it and check

Comment: If i use http://myprepa.local:8888/drawing-board/index.html cookie sets. But it's return error - Cannot GET /drawing-board/index.html

Comment: Sounds like the configuration of your static middleware isn't right then. It will try and find that file in `./drawing-board/index.html` (relative to your Node server .js file)

Comment: What do you mean "static middleware isn't right"? How to fix it?

Comment: `express.static(__dirname)` means that Express will look for static files, like `drawing-board/index.html`, in the same directory as your main JS application file. Which might not be the correct path, but it's difficult to help without knowing your directory setup.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/2239jh - server.js and app.js (client) is red

Comment: My apache settings http://prntscr.com/2239x6

Comment: `express.static(__dirname + '/../public_html/web')`

Comment: Try express.static(__dirname + '/../public_html/web') and express.static(__dirname + '/../public_html/web/drawing-board'). But still cookie empty

Comment: I can't able to see set-cookie attribute in your header. Have you noticed that?

Comment: Set cookie attribute is still empty

Comment: @user2955324, Everything is seems to be fine. Change your key from 'express.sid' to some other string and try again.

Comment: The same. Maybe something wrong with my apache configuration, because if i remove port from client init i have no cookie still, but have an error on here: http://myprepa.local/socket.io/1/websocket/iYC0zsgT4W9GAi9l0H7r?

Comment: can you add error in post?

Comment: "NetworkError: 502 Bad Gateway - http://myprepa.local/socket.io/1/websocket/PrsoLOZdIrJ1tDffIdiX"
PrsoLO...DffIdiX
Firefox can't get server connection ws://myprepa.local/socket.io/1/websocket/PrsoLOZdIrJ1tDffIdiX.
this.websocket = new Socket(this.prepareUrl() + query);

Comment: NodeJs and Apache are isolated, unless both of them are referring same port. Stop Apache service and make your node app listen to localhost and some port. If you are working in windows, make sure about your "host" file in your drivers folder.